# Using Text::CSV_XS perl module for parsing CSV with newlines

Tags: csv, text, xs

We are using `Text::CSV_XS module` for parsing CSV with the following options:

```
my $csv = Text::CSV_XS->new ({ 
                              binary=> 1, eol => "\n", 
                              allow_loose_quotes => 1, 
                              allow_loose_escapes=> 1,
                              escape_char => "\\" 
                            });
```

The CSV is created using the mysql LOAD DATA infile. If there are `NULL` values then `MYSQL` adds `\N` in the fields

Before Parsing data :

```
1973127,99,\N
```

If we use the `escape_char => "\\"` then the `\N` is replaced with `N`

Data after parsing:

```
1973127,99,N
```

Also, the data with double `'\'` are removed

eg: `D\\'Mello` changed to `D'Mello`

If we remove `escape_char => "\\"` then the data is changed as shown below

Before Parsing :

```
1539190,125,"\" SHIDDH - SHILA \"\
\"126"
```

After parsing:

```
1539190,125,\\" SHIDDH - SHILA \\"\\n\\"126
```

What is the best way to resolve this issue?

Answer (score 0):

You can clean up the CSV file first.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;

my $file = shift;
open CSV, "<$file" or die;
foreach my $line (<CSV>) {
    $line =~ s/\\N/NULL/g;
    print $line;
}
close CSV;
```

perl cleanup.pl my.csv > new.csv